# MVC 3 image button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there any way to make an @Html.actionLink an image to click instead of just a hyper link? Currently we have an old  that has an onclick attribute linking to a code behind so it needs to be converted to a link that links to the controller, not code behinds which don't exist any more in MVC3.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make an @Html.actionLink an image to click instead of just a hyper link?

No, but you could write a [custom HTML helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) that generates an image or whatever you like. In fact now tat I think you could apply a CSS class to thins anchor that applies a `background-image` to it and fixed width and height. I just don't know what you would do with the text => IIRC `Html.ActionLink` forces you to pass a non-empty `linkText` parameter as first argument. So finally the custom HTML helper doesn't seem like such a bad idea.

Comment: As Dimitrov said, you could write a custom helper for this, but I would only bother with that if you are going to use it alot, if it just to replace one button, I would just use a normal anchor tag and set the href vial @Url.Action() which would point you to a controller/action just like the @Html.ActionLink could do.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
  <p>
   <input type="image" value="submit" src="../../Images/login_button.png" alt="submit Button">
  </p>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SMART.Infrastructure
{
    public static class Html
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates and Action link with a clickable image instead of text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="helper"></param>
        /// <param name="controller">Controller</param>
        /// <param name="action">Action</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">Parameters</param>
        /// <param name="src">Image source</param>
        /// <param name="alt">Alternate text(Optional)</param>
        /// <returns>An HTML anchor tag with a nested image tag.</returns>
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionImage(this HtmlHelper helper, String controller, String action , Object parameters, String src, String alt = "", String title = "")
        {
            TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
            UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
            String url = urlHelper.Action(action, controller, parameters);
            String imgUrl = urlHelper.Content(src);
            String image = "";
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            // build the image tag.
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", imgUrl);
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("title", title);
            image = tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

            html.Append("<a href=\"");
            html.Append(url);
            html.Append("\">");
            html.Append(image);
            html.Append("</a>");

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```